# Converting a MySQL script to PostgreSQL results in "ERROR: schema does not exist" error

Tags: mysql, moodle

I have this query in MySQL that lists all Moodle courses that have been accessed in the last 2 years and the user (+ their Moodle role) that last accessed it. I'm trying to convert it to PostgreSQL 9.3.22 so it can run on another Moodle LMS I administrate. However, the query fails with the error `ERROR: schema "cat" does not exist`.

MySQL query:

```sql
select cat.id 'category id',
    cat.name 'category',
    lsl.courseid,
    c.fullname 'course fullname',
    case when c.visible = '1'
      then 'yes'
      else 'no'
    end as "course visibility",
    from_unixtime(max(lsl.timecreated), '%H:%i %D %M %Y') 'lastaccessed',
    lsl.userid 'lastaccesseduserid',
    u.username 'last accessed by',
    case when r.shortname is null
        then 'user is not enrolled in this course'
        else r.shortname
    end 'role'
from prefix_logstore_standard_log lsl
    join prefix_course c on c.id = lsl.courseid
    join prefix_course_categories cat on cat.id = c.category
    join prefix_user u on u.id = lsl.userid
    left join prefix_role_assignments ra on ra.contextid = lsl.contextid -- left join in case the last accessed user wasn't enrolled in the course (i.e. admin staff).
    left join prefix_role r on r.id = ra.roleid
group by lsl.courseid
having max(lsl.timecreated) > unix_timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 24 month))
order by lsl.courseid asc
```

My PostgreSQL conversion attempt:

```sql
select cat.id 'category id',
    cat.name 'category',
    lsl.courseid,
    c.fullname 'course fullname',
    case when c.visible = '1'
      then 'yes'
      else 'no'
    end as "course visibility",
    to_char(to_timestamp(max(lsl.timecreated)), 'HH24:MI DD/MM/YYYY') "last accessed date",
    lsl.userid 'lastaccesseduserid',
    u.username 'last accessed by',
    case when r.shortname is null
        then 'user is not enrolled in this course'
        else r.shortname 
    end "role"
from prefix_logstore_standard_log lsl
    join prefix_course c on c.id = lsl.courseid
    join prefix_course_categories cat on cat.id = c.category
    join prefix_user u on u.id = lsl.userid
    left join prefix_role_assignments ra on ra.contextid = lsl.contextid -- left join in case the last accessed user wasn't enrolled in the course (i.e. admin staff).
    left join prefix_role r on r.id = ra.roleid
group by lsl.courseid
having max(lsl.timecreated) > extract(epoch from now()- interval '2 year')
order by lsl.courseid asc
```

I checked the database's schema, and the table exists, but I don't understand why this error occurs on the prefix_course_categories table only. I don't know PostgreSQL very well, so your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: PostgreSQL does not like partial GROUP BY. Perform aggregate actions and filtering in separate subquery.

Comment: Ok, so why is it complaining about the prefix_course_categories table when there are no filters or aggregate functions performed on that table?

Comment: Maybe because `lsl` is the most left table and `courseid` is unique (maybe primary).